# Checking if the Product of n Integers is Divisible by Prime N

Tags: prime-numbers, divisibility, prime-factorization

Given $n$ integers, $x_1, ... , x_n$, is there some well-known procedure or algorithm that checks if the product $x_1 * ... * x_n$ is divisible by some arbitrary prime $N$ using minimal space?

Since the product and $N$ can be arbitrarily large, I don't think you can just simply use modular arithmetic to see if the remainder is $0$. I was thinking maybe convert the product to its prime factorization, and if $N$ isn't one of the primes used, then we know the product cannot be divisible by $N$, right? Does this seem like something that could work?

Comment: You don't need to do the multiplication, you can just check to see if $p$ divides any of $x_1,\cdots, x_n$.  Factoring is almost certainly a bad idea...that's very costly and unnecessary.

Comment: Just trial divide each $x_i$ by $p$. Then $N$ is divisible by $p$ if and only at least one $x_i$ is.

Comment: What about writing down the prime decomposition of $x_i$ first, hence deriving the prime decomposition of $x_1x_2\dotsm x_n$? Then proceed as you have written.

Answer (score 3):

Note that primes are prime: that is, if $p \mid a b$ then $p \mid a$ or $p \mid b$. (This is Euclid's lemma.) Inductively, then, if $p \mid x_1 x_2 \dots x_n$ then $p$ divides some $x_i$. So just check each of the $x_i$ in turn. Modular arithmetic is fine for that.